# Testing a Gem from old source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, testing, rubygems

I'm currently trying to convert a very old Rails 1.x plugin into a Rails4 compatible Gem.
I've managed to rewrite the code and got the framework up and running, but the tests are currently failing with the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Pages with 'id':
>   (first, {:conditions=>["url_slug = ? and parent_id IS NULL",
>   "original-page"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

I took me quite some work, but the code throwing up the error is located here:

```
acts_as_slugable_class.transaction do
   while existing != nil
       existing = acts_as_slugable_class.find(:first, conditions: ["#{slug_column} = ? and #{slug_scope_condition}", proposed_slug + suffix])
       if existing
          if suffix.empty?
             suffix = "-0"
          else
             suffix.succ!
          end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm running the tests with a basic setup using TestCase from ActiveRecord/Support and have an in memory database running with Sqlite.
Database.yml file:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
```

When I add a ***rescue nil*** at the end of the existing statement, all tests pass except the uniqueness check.
This is what my test_helper.rb file looks like:

```
# Configure Rails Environment
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require 'rails'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'active_record'
require 'active_support'
require 'yaml'
require 'acts_as_slugable'

Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# Load fixtures from the engine
if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
  ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path('../fixtures', __FILE__)
end

# run the database migrations
config = YAML::load(IO.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/database.yml'))

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/debug.log')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config[ENV['RAILS_ENV']])
load(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/schema.rb')
```

It's a bit of a hack, but I've also uploaded the source code to my github.
If anyone wants to tinker with it and help me out as to why nothing goes into the DB:

https://github.com/NekoNova/acts_as_slugable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hang on, why is there old find syntax if we're trying to make it Rails4 ready?

```
acts_as_slugable_class.transaction do
   while existing != nil
       existing = acts_as_slugable_class.where(["#{slug_column} = ? and #{slug_scope_condition}", proposed_slug + suffix]).first
       if existing
          if suffix.empty?
             suffix = "-0"
          else
             suffix.succ!
          end
        end
    end
end
```

This should also correctly return nil if the object isn't found (compared to `find`, which will raise an error if it can`t find something).

Comment: testing this. There's still a lot of old Syntax in it, which I'm working on step by step to get this working.